# Custom validation in admin for list_editable fields

Tags: django

I have a admin form with custom validation. Some of the form fields are displayed in the list view via list_editable. When I modify these fields via the list view the custom validation does not kick in. It does work when I use the regular change form, though. So the question is how do I validate changes done via the "change_list" page.

The code might make it clearer

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
    def clean(self):
        print "validating!"
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if data.get('on_frontpage') and not data.get('frontpage_image'):
            raise ValidationError('To put a project on the frontpage you must \
                                specify a "Frontpage image" first.')
        return data

class ProjectAdmin(AdminImageMixin, DisplayableAdmin, SortableAdmin):
    form = ProjectForm
    ...
    list_editable = ("status", "on_frontpage",)
    list_display = ("title", "status", "on_frontpage")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment is from a month ago, but I just answered this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. One can specify the form used on the "change_list" page by overriding "get_changelist_formset" method in ModelAdmin:
https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L524

Comment: what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: First of - edited the link to go to the correct line. I haven't done django in over a year, so I am a bit rusty. But there are two functions which map fields to forms, they are "get_changelist_form" and "get_changelist_formset". They return generic forms by default. You could probably mess with them to substitute your own form.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, I found it myself later but forgot to tell

Answer (score 4):

Override the `ModelAdmin.get_changelist_formset(request, **kwargs)` method:

```
from django.forms import BaseModelFormSet

class MyAdminFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    pass

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist_formset(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs['formset'] = MyAdminFormSet
        return super().get_changelist_formset(request, **kwargs)
```

For more details please check the [Django admin site documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_formset).

Answer (score 2):

I think @Jorge Barata's is the correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43909444/7728887), thank you very much.

Please allow me to attach a success example here.

```py
class MyAdminFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        form_set = self.cleaned_data
        for form_data in form_set:
            if form_data['field1'] != form_data['field2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(f'Item: {form_data["id"]} is not valid')

        return form_set
```

> Tested on Django 2.2