# Django admin: How to validate list_editable?

Tags: python, django

I know [someone asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598852/custom-validation-in-admin-for-list-editable-fields) this question a while ago, but the answer is incomplete and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I have a list view which displays dropdown select boxes using list_editable. When the user hits 'save' I would like to check all the dropdowns for changes and call different functions based on what they selected.

part of the admin.py file:

```
class OrdersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrdersForm
    actions = None
    list_display = ('id','order_type','number_of_items','client_name','phone_number','rent_start','number_of_days','order_state')
    list_editable = ('order_state', 'phone_number')
    search_fields = ('order_id','client_name','phone_number')
    date_hierarchy = 'rent_start'
    filter_horizontal = ('order_items',)
    ordering = ('rent_start', 'order_state',)
    list_filter = ('order_state',)
```