# How to clean and save multiple instances one after one in Django using clean and save methods?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I noticed that when using Django admin and whenever select/change multiple instances and click on save button (*for example see the below image, it's not directly related to the code below*), Django will clean/validate all instances and then save them one by one.

[image]

is this how things are working in Django or the process should be clean and then save the instance before repeat same process with the next instance? because when trying to set `is_active` value to be `true` for multiple instances, it passing the clean method condition without shown the error message that tells should only one instance be selected as `true` and that's correct cause no one of the instances have `is_active`  as `true` in the database yet ****But** if I click the save button again will show the error message**.

**models.py**:

```py
class SupplierAddress(models.Model):
    """Model to create supplier's address instances"""

    class Meta:
        """Customize django default way to plural the class name"""

        verbose_name = 'Supplier Address'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Supplier Addresses'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['supplier', 'address'],
                name='supplier_address_unique_appversion'
            )
        ]

    # Define model fields.
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        'Supplier',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='supplier_addresses_supplier'
    )
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        'Address',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='supplier_addresses_address'
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean(self):
       """Restrict the add/change to model fields"""

       if self.is_active is True:

          if SupplierAddress.objects.filter(
                  supplier=self.supplier,
                  is_active=True
          ).exclude(id=self.id).count() >= 1:
              raise forms.ValidationError(
                  {
                     "is_active": "You can't set more than one active address"
                  }
              )
```

Comment: The `clean()` method is called for each object before `save()` in order to validate the data.

Comment: @Niko Thanx for reply, I know that and this how things should be, but what I am facing is the opposite, the `clean()` is being called for all objects ( **means** `clean()` for each object) AND then `save()` for each object in order, is it timing issue? Also I set `print()` statement inside `clean()` and `save()` methods and noticed this behavior.
Correct me if I am wrong, it should be `clean()` and `save()` for each each object and then repeat same process for the next object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to reproduce your issue. What happens is that Django admin page uses a formset to save data in this kind of editable list. What you need is to override this formset (thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43909444/7100120)) and add validation to it, something like:

```
from django.forms import BaseModelFormSet

class MyAdminFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        active_count = 0
        form_set = self.cleaned_data
        for form_data in form_set:
            if form_data['is_active']:
                active_count += 1
                if active_count > 1:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('Cannot have more than one active object')
        return form_set 

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'is_active')
    list_editable = ('is_active',)

    def get_changelist_formset(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs['formset'] = MyAdminFormSet
        return super().get_changelist_formset(request, **kwargs)
```

Note that you need to adapt `MyAdminFormSet` to your problem, I just did a shallow counting of active objects in mine.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your time, it's working fine and as expected. But what about using conditional unique constraint ? take a look please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74904725/6743205)